# Post to facebook not posting full message

Tags: facebook, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to post this message to facebook :`I have achieved (".. scorepost,") points, playing... download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site`

But it is only posting: **I have achieved 1000)** 1000 is the result of **math.random(100, 1000);** that bit is working and is posting the correct number every time, but it is not posting the rest : **points, playing... download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site**

```
local facebook = require "facebook"
local fbAppID = "appID" 

scorepost =  math.random(100, 1000);    
keeping_score = true
scoreText = display.newTmessageext( "Score: " .. scorepost,  20, 20,nil, 40)
scoreText:setTextColor(255,255,255)

local faceFunc = function ()

function onLoginSuccess()
  facebook.request( "me/feed", "POST", {message = "I have achieved (".. scorepost,") points, playing... download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site"} )
end

-- facebook listener
function fbListener( event )
    if event.isError then
        native.showAlert( "ERROR", event.response, { "OK" } )
    else
        if event.type == "session" and event.phase == "login" then
            -- login was a success; call function
            onLoginSuccess()

        elseif event.type == "request" then
            -- this block is executed upon successful facebook.request() call

            native.showAlert( "Success", "The post has been uploaded.", { "OK" } )
        end
    end
end

-- photo uploading requires the "publish_stream" permission
facebook.login( fbAppID, fbListener, { "publish_stream" } )

end

--Button to activate the post to facebook
local facebutton = display.newRect (0, 0, 50, 50)
facebutton.x = display.contentWidth/2; facebutton.y = display.contentHeight/2
facebutton:addEventListener("tap", faceFunc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you concatenate the strings; like this:

```
facebook.request( "me/feed", "POST", {message = "I have achieved (".. scorepost .. ") points, playing... download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site"} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a "," instead of ".." after scorepost,
so, assuming scorepost is 100, you are sending something like:

```
{
  "message":"I have achieved (1oo",
  ") points, playing... download for FREE iPhone & Android at www.site"
}
```